# Python "and" in if statement is recognized as "or"

Tags: python

Hi I want to check if user input is long for 3 characters and the second one is space and first one and third are 1,2 or 3 so user should input
"1 3" or "2 2" etc.

I wrote this

```
correct_cord = False
cord = ["1", "2", "3"]
while not correct_cord:
    self.move = input("Enter cells: ")
    if (self.move[1] != " ") and (len(self.move) != 3):
        print("You should enter coordinates in form 'X Y'")
    else:
        if not self.move[0].isnumeric() and not self.move[2].isnumeric():
            print("You should enter numbers!")
        elif self.move[0] not in cord and self.move[2] not in cord:
            print("Coordinates should be from 1 to 3!")
        else:
            correct_cord = True
            self.move = self.move.split()
            print(self.move)
```

And the problems are:

1. when user input "x xx" it prints "You should enter numbers!" and not "You should enter coordinates in form 'X Y'" as intended - the input has 4 characters not 3 so it shouldnt pass to else statement
2. when user input "xxx" it prints "You should enter numbers!" and not "You should enter coordinates in form 'X Y'" as intended - the input has 3 characters but the second one is not space
3. when user input "1 x" it prints the result and not "You should enter numbers!" - the third character is not numeric
4. when user input "1 4"  it prints the result and not "Coordinates should be from 1 to 3!"

What is wrong with it?!

Comment: It would do a lot of good to log your actual values, and then investigate how your logic works with them in the REPL. For example, if you `print(repr(self.move))`, then that gives you a value where you you can run `move = <that value>` and then check what `move[0] not in coord`, `move[2] not in coord`, etc. do by running them at an interactive interpreter.

Comment: Walk through this by hand. If you give "x xx" as input, what is `self.move[1]`? What boolean value will that give you for `self.move[1] != " "`?

Comment: ...doing so will help you isolate a *narrow, specific* problem, instead of just dumping your code and describing its many differences from intended behavior.

Comment: `self.move` is a string like `"1 2 3"`, not a list `["1", "2", "3"]`. You may want `self.move = input(...).split()`.

Comment: It seems to me that several of your “and”s should be “or”s

Comment: Can you explain why you think `'x xx'` should print `"You should enter coordinates in form 'X Y'"`?  Keep in mind that *both* of your checks must pass since you used `and` instead of `or`.

Comment: @Nathan when I type "abcd" and print self.move[1] it prints "b" so in "x xx" it should be " " right?

Answer (score 2):

Break the problem down:

```py
self.move = input("Enter cells: ")    # <-- user enters "x xx"
```

Now, the following statements hold:

```py
(self.move == "x xx") == True
```

```py
(self.move[1] != " ") == False        # the second character is a space
(len(self.move) != 3) == True         # the length is not 3
```

Because you've paired this with the `and` operator, you end up with:

```py
(False and True) == False             # they aren't both True
```

```py
if False:
    print("You should enter coordinates in form 'X Y'")
else:
    ...
```

Which correctly takes the `else` branch - your logic is flawed.

---

You probably want to swap `and` for `or`, as failing *either*  of these tests should trigger the warning (not failing *both* of the tests).

```py
(self.move[1] != " ") == False        # the second character is a space
(len(self.move) != 3) == True         # the length is not 3
if False or True:
    print("You should enter coordinates in form 'X Y'")
else:
    ...
```

Another approach could be to do "*positive*" tests, which can help with reasoning - it's very easy to get confused with negatives... Here we confirm if "*all of our tests pass*" (before inverting the result with `not`), instead of testing if "*any of our tests fail*".

```py
if not ( (self.move[1] == " ") and (len(self.move) == 3) ):
    print("You should enter coordinates in form 'X Y'")
else:
    ...
```

---

As a general note, it's also wise to test the bounds of a variable before trying to access its contents.

In the following example, the `len(x) == 3` will fail before the `x[1] == " "` is checked, and the test will [short circuit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not), meaning that the `x[1]` will never even be evaluated, and you won't get an `IndexError` exception raised.

```py
if not ( (len(self.move) == 3) and (self.move[1] == " ") ):
    print("You should enter coordinates in form 'X Y'")
else:
    ...
```

Here, `b()` will never be called:

```py
>>> def a():
...     print('a')
...     return False
...
>>> def b():
...     print('b')
...     return True
...
>>> if a() and b():
...     print('yay')
... else:
...     print('boo')
...
a
boo
```

Answer (score 0):

It should really be

```
if (self.move[1] != " ") or (len(self.move) != 3):
```

isn't it?
Likewise for all other `and` operations.

In the case of `if condition_1 and condition_2`:, if `condition_1` turns out to be `False`, Python won't evaluate `condition_2` because the net result is anyway the same. Similarly, in the case of `if condition_1 or condition_2:`, if `condition_1` turns out to be `True`, `condition_2` will not be evaluated. This is called short circuiting.

Answer (score 0):

Hehe, this is what makes programming so annoying, all I did was change one word, and clean the code up a bit, I don't get why you used the else statement but anyway, as the other two answers say, yes it's supposed to be or,

This is because you want the elements to be a compliment in both conditions if you want that, what you should have done is

```
if not (move[1] == " ") and (len(move) == 3):
```

The format you want is 'x xx', so if it is 'xx x', it does not comply, therefore, you need the OR keyword, because your looking for either of the two to be wrong because then the format isn't right

```
    correct_cord = False
cord = ["1", "2", "3"]

while not correct_cord:
    move = input("Enter cells: ")
    print(len(move))
    if (move[1] != " ") or (len(move) != 3):
        print("You should enter coordinates in form 'X Y'")
    elif not move[0].isnumeric() and not move[2].isnumeric():
        print("You should enter numbers!")
    elif move[0] not in cord and move[2] not in cord:
        print("Coordinates should be from 1 to 3!")
    else:
        correct_cord = True
        move = move.split()
        print(move)
```

If you still don't understand, basically in your comment you said you need that

self.move[1] should be " " and length should be 3

If EITHER of them isn't true, then that's not formatted correctly,

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it now.
It should be like that:

```
correct_cord = False
cord = ["1", "2", "3"]
while not correct_cord:
    self.move = input("Enter cells: ")
    if (self.move[1] == " ") and (len(self.move) == 3):
        if not self.move[0].isnumeric() or not self.move[2].isnumeric():
            print("You should enter numbers!")
        elif self.move[0] not in cord or self.move[2] not in cord:
            print("Coordinates should be from 1 to 3!")
        else:
            correct_cord = True
            self.move = self.move.split()
            print(self.move)
    else:
        print("You should enter coordinates in form 'X Y'")
```

Thanks all for help

Comment: I think it would be better if you put that in your question....

Comment: Sorry I am new here. Dont know how things works here.